# Refactoring compiler from 0.4.0 to 0.8.7

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

I am new to solidity and i want to know what I am doing wrong to my code. The compiler tells me many times to use memory or storage as a solution.

Here is my code. I hope somebody can help me out. I am just making a voting contract to test out solidity.

In the image you can see the errors that I'm getting.

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Voter{

//Make a struct
struct OptionPos {
    uint pos;
    bool exists;
}

uint[] public votes;
string[] public options;
mapping(address => bool) hasVoted;
mapping(string => OptionPos) posOfOption;

//constructor that initialize properties
constructor(string[] _options) public {
    options = _options;
    votes.length = options.length;

    // forlus to fill al existing options to the mapping posOfOption
    for(uint i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        OptionPos memory optionPos = OptionPos(i, true);
        string optionName = options[i];
        posOfOption[optionName] = optionPos;
    }
}

// an number gets past the numer needs to be bigger than 0 and smaller then 
// the length of the array if so the index that matches the given number will increase with on
function vote(uint option) public {
    require(0 <= option && option < options.length, "Invalid option");
    //check if adress already has voted
    require(!hasVoted[msg.sender], "Account has already voted");

    //increment with +1
    votes[option] = votes[option] + 1;

    //change adres to status has voted 
    hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
}

function vote(string optionName) public {
    //Check if adress has already voted
    require(!hasVoted[msg.sender], "Account has already voted");

    //put the optionName in memory for later
    OptionPos memory optionPos = posOfOption[optionName];

    //check if the input value exists
    require(optionPos.exists, "Option doesn't exist.");
    votes[optionPos.pos] = votes[optionPos.pos] + 1;

    //set address voted to true
    hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
}

// returns a list of al votes orderd by index 
function getOption() public view returns (string[]) {
    return options;
}

// Returns amount of votes equals to the index that you have given 
function getVotes() public view returns (uint[]) {
    return votes;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add keyword `memory` after `string` variable.

Example:

```
string memory optionName



string[] memory_options
```